# Variable como función

Tags: javascript, html, condiciones

Necesito realizar un programa que me indique el rumbo de dos puntos, para lo cual tengo este codigo, pero me gustaria que la variable del condicional sea tomada de una caja donde tenga que digitarla y que deba una vez digitada la variable dar click a un botón para que se muestre la respuesta. Dicha respuesta la tengo como condicional.

1. Llamado de una caja.
2. Botón que haga la operación.
3. Caja donde se muestre la respuesta.

Código:

```
var x1=110;
if (x1>= 0 && x1<= 90){
    a=document.write("Rumbo: N"+x1+"E");
} else if (x1>90 && x1<= 180){      
    a1=document.write("Rumbo: S"+x1+" E");
} else if (x1>180 && x1<=270){
    a2=document.write("Rumbo: S"+x1+"W");
} else { 
    a3=document.write("Rumbo: N"+x1+"W");
}
```

Tengo que `x1=document.getElementById("b").value;`, para llamar a `x1`, pero no sé cómo colocar el `if` como una variable, y que esta se lea en una caja.

Comment: Un cuadro puede ser un `textarea`, o `input` en un html, `<textarea id="cuadro"></textarea>`, y el valor se obtiene así,  desde javascript, `cuadro.value`.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar unos ejemplos?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Puedes usar **eval()**, que es una funcion de javascript que te permite ejecutar una expresion.

```
var x = 10;
var y = 20;
var a = eval("x * y") + "<br>";
var b = eval("2 + 2") + "<br>";
var c = eval("x + 17") + "<br>";

var res = a + b + c;
```

> Pero ten en cuenta lo peligroso de aceptar cualquier entrada del
>   usuario como codigo valido. Deberias validar la entrada del usuario
>   con una expresion regular para eliminar codigo javascript peligroso y
>   solo dejar que el usuario ingrese lo que tu necesitas, probablemente
>   solo operadores basicos.

```
var x1=110;

var expression1 = document.getElementById("txtExpression1").value;
var expression2 = document.getElementById("txtExpression2").value;
var expression3 = document.getElementById("txtExpression3").value;

if (eval(expression1))
{
    a=document.write("Rumbo: N"+x1+"E");
} else if (eval(expression2)){      
     a1=document.write("Rumbo: S"+x1+" E");
} else if (eval(expression3)){
     a2=document.write("Rumbo: S"+x1+"W");    
} else { 
     a3=document.write("Rumbo: N"+x1+"W");
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la información, fue de gran ayuda, pero si no es mucha molestia ahora tengo una duda, quiero que mi respuesta me quede dentro de un cuadro , que tendria que hacer? muchas gracias